# How to render template with Koa

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

My effort is to re-engineer my app from Express to Koa, so routes.js and controllers.js work previously. I try to create a small mechanism to render template in Koa. The goal is to apply the working code for other modules loading **different template engines** automatically through render variable calling module.view_engine per module.routes . Can you help?

```
+---modules
|   +---core
|   |   +---client
|   |   |   \---views
|   |   |           equipment.pug
|   |   |           error.pug
|   |   |           home.pug
|   |   |           
|   |   \---server
|   |       +---configs
|   |       |       core.config.json
|   |       |       core.koa.configs.js
|   |       |       
|   |       +---controllers
|   |       |       core.server.controllers.js
|   |       |       
|   |       +---models
|   |       |       assembly.server.model.js
|   |       |       ecms_equipment.server.model.js
|   |       |       ecms_location.server.model.js
|   |       |       ecms_main.server.model.js
|   |       |       index.js
|   |       |       
|   |       \---routes
|   |               core.server.routes.js
|   |               
|   +---assemblys
|   |   +---client
|   |   |   \---views
|   |   |           assembly_view.pug
|   |   |           
|   |   \---server
|   |       +---controllers
|   |       |       assemblys.server.controllers.js
|   |       |       
|   |       \---routes
|   |               assemblys.server.routes.js
```

That's my directory structure. With a couple of Lodash each loop, I am able to achieve view_path, routes, view_engine per module in core.koa.configs.js

```
modules[module] = {
    view_path: view_path,
    routes: routes,
    view_engine: view_engine
  };
```

In the same file, with `module` still inside the `_.each` loop, I call

```
// regex to narrow the scope of code experimenting
if (module.re('assemblys')) {
    // === var render here? ===
    require(routes)(app);
  }
```

That takes the app to the assembly.server.routes.js containing the following:

```
var controller  = require('../controllers/projects.server.controllers');


module.exports = function(app){
  app.get('/task', controller.assembly)
};
```

Then, in the assembly.server.controllers.js, I try to provide the assembly function but it doesn't work - 404 :

```
// load Sequelize models
var models = require( process.cwd() + '/modules/core/server/models');

exports.assembly = function *() {
  var that = this.body, views = require('co-views');
  var render = views('../../client/views/' , {
    map: {pug: 'jade'}
  });
  var Assembly = models.Assembly;

  Assembly.findAll().then(function (assemblys) {
    that = yield render('assembly_view' , {assemblys: assemblys});
  });
};
```

Previously, I put `var render` inside the core.configs to be able to use view_path right there but then when I pass `render` into `function *()`, I got error and app crash! When render was in core.configs, I had the routes.js file exporting this:

```
module.exports = function(app, render){
      app.get('/task', controller.assembly(render));
    };
```

Some Koa examples says using `route` in this `app.use(route.get('/assembly', function *() { });`
and I saw some other examples simply use this

```
app.get('/task', controller.assembly(render)); // cnpmjs.org, koan stack...
```

I prefer the latter. But having trouble with `yield render` and how to load app, render parameters into the `function *(app,render)` generator, I tried this but it doesn't work too. Error in stack trace.

**The idea result is to have in core.koa.configs.js** :

```
if (module.re('assemblys')) {
    var render = views(view_path , {
        map: view_engine
    });
    require(routes)(app, render);
}
```

then exporting routes

```
module.exports = function(app, render){
  app.get('/task', controller.assembly(render))
};
```

and the controller is able to render the assemblys:

```
exports.assembly = function *(render) {
  var that = this.body, views = require('co-views');
  var Assembly = models.Assembly;

  Assembly.findAll().then(function (assemblys) {
    that = yield render('assembly_view' , {assemblys: assemblys});
  });
};
```

Update: See [stack-traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBlTp.jpg), see [koa branch_commit](https://github.com/zenithtekla/nodeMySQL/commits/with_koa). -compiled.js.map files were generated by ES6-Babel

Comment: Do you have any logging information from the console about the 404 you're receiving? Wouldn't surprise me if it's working as expected, but the 404 is coming from your Pug file.

Comment: Thank you for your input. http://imgur.com/a/A79vG Update with stack-traces. 

I use co-views service, do you need my packages.json?

Answer (score 0):

Koa (unlike express) does not wait until you will set the response body. If your middleware function ended, and the response body is empty, it will give a 404 response. That's why, in koa you should avoid callbacks or promisify them.

Here is how your middleware function should look like in koa-style:

```
exports.assembly = function *(render) {
    var that = this.body, views = require('co-views');
    var Assembly = models.Assembly;

    var assemblys = yield Assembly.findAll();
    that = yield render('assembly_view' , {assemblys: assemblys});
};
```